# How to use Win 7 command line with folder with "My" prefix

Tags: windows-7, command-line, my-documents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display “My Documents”/“My Videos”/etc. without “My” prefix in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/79447/display-my-documents-my-videos-etc-without-my-prefix-in-windows-7)

What is the "right" way to get rid of the "My" prefix in Windows 7? I renamed (F2) the documents, music, pictures, and videos folders to remove the "My" prefix and the "My Documents" folder reappears every so often.

The reason I deleted the "My" prefixes is that I like to use the command line to move/copy files/folders and if I use tab completion to "Documents," it ends up making a new folder (at least with `xcopy`). When I use tab complete in Vim I don't have any of these problems.

Is there a right way to use the command line in Windows 7? I see lots of questions "My" prefixes, but I can't seem to find any that address the best way to use them with the command line (and hopefully keep the ability to use Live Mesh).

Edit:

I followed [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-do-i-remove-the-my-documents-folder/4c9516ab-43aa-41c5-84ed-10a885a485a5?tm=1327343793101) at answers.microsoft.com and right-clicked the "My Documents" folder that keeps returning and changed the location to "Documents," which allowed me to merge the two folders (the regenerated "My Documents" was empty). This left me with a "Documents" folder with the original "My Documents" icon of a folder with no paper and no "My Documents" folder. Should I be happy with this and carry on? I like the ability to move/copy/open files from the terminal. Is this possible in Windows? Or do the "My" prefixes necessarily cause headaches? Thanks!

Comment: @techie007 -- Thanks! I think you are right, mine is a duplicate. I should have done that _before_ I just went changing folder names. But I think what I've done is the right fix. I think?